# How to initalize a variadic number of templates at compile time in consteval

Tags: c++, templates

predef_ts() returns an array of sizes of an object representation(when in a variant) of the template Ts type parameters at compile time by iterating through variant_typesize<>(), which creates a seperate template instantiation for every iterator.

on the line: **s_arr[i] = variant_typesize<it, Ts...>();**, a instantiation of the template is created with the iterator it declared at line: **const std::size_t it = i**. When the value of it is a const rvalue such as 1 or 2, everything works as expected, but if it is set to any non-const value, the below error is thrown.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘variant_typesize< ... >()
```

Since this all needs to happen at compile time, I obviously cant const_cast or break type safety completely. I seem to get the impression that consteval templates cannot be instantiated from another consteval function if any of the template types are modified by the caller function.

Despite this, it seems that this should be possible since the amount of template parameters are known when the variant_typesize<>() templates are being initalized. I feel like I'm missing something here though since this seems like a common thing to do. The code for this is below.

```
std::size_t is;
template <std::size_t it, typename... Ts>
[[nodiscard]] std::size_t
consteval variant_typesize()
{
    assert(it < sizeof...(Ts));                         
    std::variant<Ts...> table[] = { Ts{ }... };         
    return sizeof( std::get<it, Ts...>(table[it]) );    
}

template <typename... Ts>
consteval std::array<std::size_t, std::variant_size_v< std::variant<Ts...> > > predef_ts()
{
    typedef std::variant<Ts...> ts_variant;                           
    std::array<std::size_t, std::variant_size_v<ts_variant>> s_arr{}; 
    for(uint16_t i=0; i < s_arr.size(); i++)
    {
        const std::size_t it = i;     // if this value is a const rvalue like 1, everything works fine
        s_arr[i] = variant_typesize<it, Ts...>(); 
    }                   
    return s_arr;                                                     
};
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why `variant` matters. `variant_typesize` just returns a size of the `it`th type in `Ts`, does it not? What's the point of packing types into variants just to extract a type right back, merely to take its `sizeof`? What's the point of actually instantiating a `table` array? The size of a type doesn't depend on how an object of that type is constructed.

Comment: In what way is `predef_ts` different from `template <typename... Ts> constexpr auto predef_ts() { return std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>{sizeof(Ts)...}; }` ? I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, this is correct, I was unsure if the ordering would change if a variant was not used but this works perfectly. Thank you.